# Publishing MBTiles online, issue with .json file or mb-util extraction

Tags: json, leaflet, mapbox, mbtiles

I've been trying to display my .mbtiles on the browser inside a "map-div". I extracted the .mbtiles into .png tile files and a .json file using [mb-util](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil)

This is how my server's public_html looks like:  [image]

Tiles folder:  [image]

metadata.json inside tiles folder:  [image]

And main javascript file java.js:  [image]

Inside java.js there's the code from the [Wax connector](http://www.mapbox.com/wax/connector-leaf.html) so I can use the .json to work with Leaflet.

The map in this state does not work.

So I uploaded the mbtiles file to the MapBox hosting and fetch the .json URL. And when the URL http://testit969.host22.com/tileserver/century.json in java.js is replaced by the Mapbox generated .json URL, it displays the map (although the interactivity doesn't work). This shows me at least that the code is sufficient to display a map provided the .json file is OK.

But right now, the map doesn't display at all. It displays the Leaflet map container only in gray.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're using Leaflet I would suggest you to use "Leaflet.Utfgrid" (https://github.com/danzel/Leaflet.utfgrid) instead of Wax. Soooo much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [MapBox.js v1.x](http://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-js-with-leaflet/) or later - the old-style Wax/Leaflet integration is no longer supported. And we can give better assistance in [support.mapbox.com](http://support.mapbox.com/).

Comment: With the help of the new documentation for version 1.3.1, got the map working. Thanks! http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.3.1/